# Como puedo estructurar una base de datos que maneja multiples tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos, tablas, estructuras

Actualmente tenemos una base de datos que maneja un punto de venta donde le prestamos el servicio a varias compañias. En esta base de datos tenemos una tabla de productos, una tabla de facturas, y muchas tablas comunes para todas las compañias.

Como esta pagina esta en Godaddy, no hay problema por ahora ya que uno puede crear multiples bases de datos pero estas tienen un limite de 1048 MB por BD. Un problema a futuro por el crecimiento que esta teniendo el software. Podria crear una Base de datos por compañias por mi plan de desarrollo no es viable.

Tengo planteado pasarlo a AWS, por lo que quiero manejar una base de datos para todas las compañias pero dividir mas bien por tablas las mismas, ya que a nivel de precios crear bases de datos por cada compañia  es mucho mas caro que lo q me costaria en Godaddy por lo que me he planteado es migrar todo a una Base de Datos manejar Multiples Tablas.

He planteado la siguiente estructura. (basededatos_tabla_cedulacompania)

```
db_productos_123456789
db_productos-222222222
db_productos-333333333
db_facturas_123456789
db_facturas_222222222
db_facturas_333333333
```

Otra Opcion seria:

```
db_123456789_facturas
db_123456789_productos
db_222222222_facturas
db_222222222_productos
db_333333333_facturas
db_333333333_productos
```

Esto es factible el tema es que al momento de visualizar es muy engorroso y no se si hay limites de tablas en las bases de datos.

**Hay alguna forma de como a nivel visual meter estas tablas en carpetas ejemplo todos los productos o todas las compañias en una carpeta y al momento de visualizar seria mas facil, algo asi como emular que estan en bases de datos diferentes pero mediante tablas?**

Comment: Otra opción es incluir el concepto de multitenancy en tu aplicación, reusar la estructura actual de tablas y añadir algunas tablas / columnas que permitan identificar la pertenencia de los datos a uno u otro tenant

Comment: si, la tabla actual maneja campos de compañias y sucursales, por lo que fácilmente se puede al momento de consultar separarlas, el tema es que por BD Godaddy tiene limites de almacenamiento y pensando a futuro prefiero ir cambiando la estructura de una vez.